# Filter lookup query using row value in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, lookup

I have two tables:

**A**

- ID
- Name
- DateA

**B**

- ID
- IDA
- DateB

When I am in Stylesheet view, I want to drop down the column IDA in Table B, a show a list containing all the A elements that have DateA property = to the selected B element's date row.

I tried to do this using a lookup on the IDA column that references Table A and setting Criteria of A.DateA on `[A]![DateA]` and many other variants, but it doesn't work.

Can you help me please?

Thanks